# Android Studio doesn't show me any device when I want to run the app

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

Hi a few days ago I updated Android Studio and now when I want to run an application doesn't show me any device, I use Genymotion sometimes to emulate or my phone but now it doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after upgrading AS. I solved it like this:

1. I installed the genymotion plugin (before that I ran the standalone genymotion app and loaded the emulators)
2. First I click the Run 'app' green button and wait a few secs for the window to load the adb emulators (i have installed a few)
3. As soon as the emulators are loaded in the window I close the window
4. I run the genymotion plugin and start the emulator I want
5. After all that the genymotion emulator is there when I click the Run button

It works for me  
Maybe a fresh installation of genymotion would solve the problem but I haven't tried it yet